# Add Class to href element

Tags: jquery

I want to add class 'sidebarActive' to 'sidebarButton' when I scroll past a section. Each 'sidebarButton' has 'href' that corresponds to a section with id.
I have set up an example which works - when I scroll past section with id #four, the '.sidebarButton' with that href gets the class 'sidebarActive' added. How do I expand this concept to target all 'sidebarButton' elements and their hrefs at the same time.?

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var os = $('#four').offset().top;
        var ht = $('#four').height();
        if(scroll > os - ht){
           $('.sidebarButton[href="#four"]').addClass('sidebarActive');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target all `.sideBarButton`'s and [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) only those element which fulfills the criteria

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        //Target all element and remove class
        $('.sidebarButton[href]').removeClass('sidebarActive')
            //Use the filter to get the matching elements
            .filter(function () {
                var os = $(this.href).offset().top;
                var ht = $(this.href).height();
                return (scroll > (os - ht));
            }).addClass('sidebarActive');
    });
});
```